# Download spreadsheet to CSV with Python and GSpread

Tags: python, csv, spreadsheet, gspread

With this code I can download all the sheets that are in the spreadsheet to csv.
but i just want to download a sheet.
Is there how to do it?

Code

```
import csv
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

docid = "123"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(docid)
for i, worksheet in enumerate(spreadsheet.worksheets()):
    filename = docid + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

If anyone knows, please let me know.

[From these documents I obtained information](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

Comment: What do you mean by "download a sheet"? Download just ONE sheet or download as an excel file rather than csv?

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I just want to download just one sheet and do it in csv.

Comment: so what format do you want to download as?

Comment: in csv I want to download.

Comment: Do you know which sheet you want? You code is making a csv file for each worksheet. But I understand you only want one. Which one?

Comment: thank you for the message . I want the second sheet called "sheet2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method to get the worksheet by name should work for you.

### Example (Only printing "sheet2"):

```py
import csv
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

docid = "123"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(docid)
worksheetName = "sheet2"
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(worksheetName)
filename = docid + '-worksheet' + worksheetName + '.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

Comment: Why use a for loop at all if you only want to handle *one* case?

Comment: thanks with this you can download the single spreadsheet